# How can I set the level of precision for Raku's sqrt?

Tags: perl, raku, sqrt, arbitrary-precision

With Perl, one could use `bignum` to set the level of precision for all operators. As in:

```
use bignum ( p => -50 );

print sqrt(20);    # 4.47213595499957939281834733746255247088123671922305
```

With Raku I have no problems with rationals since I can use `Rat` / `FatRat`, but I don't know how to use a longer level of precision for sqrt

```
say 20.sqrt # 4.47213595499958
```

Comment: Here is a non-answer: 1) You can change the _printed_ precision with `sprintf`.  But this does not increase the actual precision – `say sprintf('%.50f', 20.sqrt)` prints `4.47213595499958000000000000000000000000000000000000`.  I am not aware of a way to change the _actual_ precision of the `Num` type in Raku, though I'd certainly be interested in learning otherwise.  Thanks for the interesting question.

Comment: How does Perl's `bignum` do that? If it's just altering the *printed* precision, see @codesections' comment above.  If it's altering the *computed* precision, what numerical techniques/library is it using?

Comment: @raiph, I don't know about the inners workings in perl, but I believe that is not just a simple *printed* precission, as I can set a precissión of `10,000` and the extra digits are not 'zeroed'. Not to mention that it takes a lot to compute (7 seconds for a sqrt(20) with 10,000 digits of precision)

Comment: OK, so I checked perl's internals. `Math::BigInt::Calc;` provides a `_sqrt` method for bigints that reads `square-root of $x in place. Compute a guess of the result (by rule of thumb), then improve it via Newton's method.`. That `_sqrt` method is called on the package `Math::BigFloat` by the `bsqrt` method. That `bsqrt` method does (amon other things): `sqrt(2) = 1.4 because sqrt(2*100) = 1.4*10; so we can increase the accuracy of the result by multiplying the input by 100 and then divide the integer result of sqrt(input) by 10. Rounding afterwards returns the real result.`

Comment: Links to sources (see my previous comment): [Math::BigInt::Calc](https://metacpan.org/release/Math-BigInt/source/lib/Math/BigInt/Calc.pm) and [Math::BigFloat](https://metacpan.org/release/Math-BigInt/source/lib/Math/BigFloat.pm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated on Elizabeth's answer, `sqrt` returns a `Num` type, thus it has limited precision. See Elizabeth's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63485381/7500028) for more detail.

For that reason I created a raku class: [BigRoot](https://github.com/juliodcs/BigRoot), which uses newton's method and `FatRat` types to calculate the roots. You may use it like this:

```
use BigRoot;

# Can change precision level (Default precision is 30)
BigRoot.precision = 50;

my $root2 = BigRoot.newton's-sqrt: 2;
# 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537695

say $root2.WHAT;
# (FatRat)

# Can use other root numbers
say BigRoot.newton's-root: root => 3, number => 30;
# 3.10723250595385886687766242752238636285490682906742

# Numbers can be Int, Rational and Num:
say BigRoot.newton's-sqrt: 2.123;
# 1.45705181788431944566113502812562734420538186940001

# Can use other rational roots
say BigRoot.newton's-root: root => FatRat.new(2, 3), number => 30;
# 164.31676725154983403709093484024064018582340849939498

# Results are rounded:

BigRoot.precision = 8;
say BigRoot.newton's-sqrt: 2;
# 1.41421356

BigRoot.precision = 7;
say BigRoot.newton's-sqrt: 2;
# 1.4142136
```

In general it seems to be pretty fast (at least compared to Perl's bigfloat)

**Benchmarks:**

```
|---------------------------------------|-------------|------------|
|  sqrt with 10_000 precision digits    |    Raku     |    Perl    |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|------------|
|  20000000000                          |    0.714    |   3.713    |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|------------|
|  200000.1234                          |    1.078    |   4.269    |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|------------|
|  π                                    |    0.879    |   3.677    |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|------------|
|  123.9/12.29                          |    0.871    |   9.667    |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|------------|
|  999999999999999999999999999999999    |    1.208    |   3.937    |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|------------|
|  302187301.3727 / 123.30219380928137  |    1.528    |   7.587    |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|------------|
|  2 + 999999999999 ** 10               |    2.193    |   3.616    |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|------------|
|  91200937373737999999997301.3727 / π  |    1.076    |   7.419    |
|---------------------------------------|-------------|------------|
```

If want to implement your own `sqrt` using newton's method, this the basic idea behind it:

```
sub newtons-sqrt(:$number, :$precision) returns FatRat {
    my FatRat $error = FatRat.new: 1, 10 ** ($precision + 1);
    my FatRat $guess = (sqrt $number).FatRat;
    my FatRat $input = $number.FatRat;
    my FatRat $diff = $input;

    while $diff > $error {
        my FatRat $new-guess = $guess - (($guess ** 2 - $input) / (2 * $guess));
        $diff = abs($new-guess - $guess);
        $guess = $new-guess;
    }

    return $guess.round: FatRat.new: 1, 10 ** $precision;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will only work for small integers. In my tests it works great for 10,000 digits of the square root of `2`, is OK for  `20`, but is awfully slow for `200`.

Comment: But it's still nice to see this. :) I've created tinyurl.com/raku-newtons-method as a permanent URL linking to a variant of your code. I didn't change Newton's method (!) but just altered the last couple lines of code to compare the number calculated with a set of digits slurped from Input. I chose 2 as the number to square root because there's a convenient public source for the correct first 10,000 digits.

Comment: Hehe, I did same test on local with first 100_000 sqrt(2) digits. I guess newthon's method works!! :-) You are right it is not really fast with big numbers. But at least it is comparable (if not faster) to Perl's version.

Comment: Hi @raiph, I made some improvements. It seems that the slow bigger ints issue was because of my poor choice for the first guess number (which was `number/2`) I knew it was not very accurate, but I expected the algorithm to cath the real number 'soon'. But that was not the case for bigger numbers, since the bigger the number, the bigger is the difference from `number/2` to the final sqrt. So now I'm using raku's original sqrt as the first guess and now there is no difference from small numbers to big ones. I also changed the code to being able to accept a Rational number aswell.

Comment: \o/ Smokin'! How large is "large numbers"? What about a 20,000 digit integer or a `FatRat` with a random 1,000 digit numerator and denominator? I guess the main thing is that the iterative aspect does no division, and instead just addition and subtraction of integers, plus one integer square.

Comment: @raiph, I added some benchmarks and changed the code to allow for input `Num`, `Rational` and `Int`

Comment: Would consider putting this logic into a module?  Or allow someone else to put it in a module?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Sure! I was planning to add a module for this. Perhaps make it more generic to allow for any type of root, not just square roots. Perhaps even higher precision constants such `pi`, `e`, ... would be welcome. Do you think we have any chance a module like this would make into core? If so, what changes what we need to do?

Comment: @Julio: so far, only one module made it from the ecosystem to the core: `NativeCall`.  But having it in the ecosystem would already be pretty good!  And inclusion in a package such as Rakudo Star would be much more likely.

Comment: I finally created the module, thank you for your suggestions and hints

Answer (score 6):

In Rakudo, `sqrt` is implemented using the `sqrt_n` NQP opcode.  Which indicates it only supports native nums (because of the `_n` suffix).  Which implies limited precision.

Internally, I'm pretty sure this just maps to the sqrt functionality of one of the underlying math libraries that MoarVM uses.

I guess what we need is an ecosystem module that would export a `sqrt` function based on `Rational` arithmetic.  That would give you the option to use higher precision `sqrt` implementations at the expense of performance.  Which then in turn, might turn out to be interesting enough to integrate in core.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a rational `sqrt` would almost never help, and would usually make things a lot worse. ❶ Per math, a rational `sqrt` *can't* help with *any* irrational numbers (which would of course be stored as `Num`s) and *can't* return an accurate result for *almost all* rational numbers, even using `FatRat`s. ❷ Most `Num`s where float precision matters are already inaccurate, so converting them to `Rational` equivalents wouldn't help. ❸ For the sorts of numbers where precision of floats (`Num`s) matters, using a rational `sqrt` would almost always be *pathologically slow*.

Comment: @raiph I tried a rational sqrt (using newthon's method) and It is pretty fast (at least compared to Perl's bigfloat)

Comment: Heh. I will leave my original comment up as yet another reminder to myself and others of just how wrong I can be. (I was right about the math but thoroughly wrong about the computer science / reality.)